# Parse Laravel Array

Tags: laravel

This seems like a very basic question, but I just cannot figure it out. I am trying to parse through this array in a blade template.

I am saving data to a session variable that is an array. When I dd the variable in the view I get this...

```
"[["Less than $50,000","$50,000-$100,000","More than $100,000"],["Step2-option1","Step2-option2"],["Step3-option2"]]"
```

It looks like it's saving to the database as a string instead of an array. Is that correct? When I try to dd($variable[0]) I only get "[". If it is a string, I need to be saving it another way or at least taking this and converting it back to an array.

Each piece of this "array" is from a multi-step form that I am aggregating into a session variable using Session::push();

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you saving/storing the data? Show that part of your code.

Comment: Can you try `json_decode` first? then show us the new result. add `true` also as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: I don't know how it would work if you don't have escaped double quotes or used combination of single quotes/double quotes there. And secondly, we don't know your DB structure to help with insert.

Comment: Also try to figure out why it shows like that, because it shouldn't be like that. Try to show us the code how you inserted the data into session.

Comment: Wow...json_decode was the way. I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks, Vandolph! Feel free to submit that as an answer if you like and I'll check it.

Comment: Thats great. Can I add this to the answer and accept it?

Comment: Yes, please do!

Comment: Done sir. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_decode`, if still not working, try to add `true` in the 2nd parameter.